# Implement a partition function using a fold in Scala

Tags: scala, fold

I'm new to Scala and I want to write a higher-order function (say "partition2") that takes a list of integers and a function that returns either true or false. The output would be a list of values for which the function is true and a list of values for which the function is false. I'd like to implement this using a fold. I know something like this would be a really straightforward way to do this:

```
val (passed, failed) = List(49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90) partition ( _ > 60 )
```

I'm wondering how this same logic could be applied using a fold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by thinking about what you want your accumulator to look like. In many cases it'll have the same type as the thing you want to end up with, and that works here—you can use two lists to keep track of the elements that passed and failed. Then you just need to write the cases and add the element to the appropriate list:

```
List(49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90).foldRight((List.empty[Int], List.empty[Int])) {
  case (i, (passed, failed)) if i > 60 => (i :: passed, failed)
  case (i, (passed, failed)) => (passed, i :: failed)
}
```

I'm using a right fold here because prepending to a list is nicer than the alternative, but you could easily rewrite it to use a left fold.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! My problem is now that I'm having trouble implementing this as a a higher-order function (ie what if the function I want to pass in varies as something other than i > 60). I think I'm just having trouble grasping the syntax.

Comment: Yeah, it's essentially the same—you'll just have `if p(i)` instead of `if i > 60`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
List(49, 58, 76, 82, 88, 90).foldLeft((Vector.empty[Int], Vector.empty[Int])){
  case ((passed, failed), x) => 
    if (x > 60) (passed :+ x, failed)
    else (passed, failed :+ x)
}
```

Basically you have two accumulators, and as you visit each element, you add it to the appropriate accumulator.